# Getting PSEXEC to run a local .vbs file on a remote machine without copying it over

Tags: telnet, remote-access, psexec, sysinternals

I would like to get `PSEXEC` to run a `.vbs` file on a remote machine for me, however I currently have to have the `.vbs` located on the remote machine.

Below is an example of my script which does work.

```
psexec \\<\i.pAddress\> -u <\User\> -p <\Password\> -w c:\ -h cscript.exe "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test.vbs"
```

Is there any solution which saves me having to place the `test.vbs` file on the remote machine before hand?

Answer (score 1):

Use the -c option (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

-c  Copy the specified program to the remote system for execution. If you omit this option the application must be in the system path on the remote system.

Comment: Thanks for the response does the -c option execute a .vbs file?